# Get owner by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this class Company:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
  after_create :set_owner

  def set_owner
    owner.update_attributes(company_id: id, role_id: 0)
  end
```

and this class User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company, foreign_key: :owner_id
  belongs_to :team, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: :company_id
```

A company can only have one owner, but can have many other users.

This all works fine, for new signups I do this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.build_company
end
```

However now I would like to get the owner name during initialisation of a new company.

If I do this in the console:

```
u = User.new(:name => 'My Name', :email => 'test@mail.com')
c = u.build_company(:name => 'my company')
c.owner
 => nil
c.users.count
 => 0
```

How can I do this?  I want to get the user that build the company in the initialisation phase (to be able to get the user's name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by adding `inverse_of` this way the built instance will be aware of the relation

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :company, foreign_key: :owner_id, inverse_of: :owner
end
```